# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.2/mule.xsd'

Tags: mule

i am trying to do a simple JMS program with an http end point and a jms connector.
but iam getting below error messsage. Please help me to resolve it.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesource.org/schema/mule/core/2.2/mule.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:297)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
INFO  2014-12-22 20:53:09,919 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Disposing RegistryBroker
ERROR 2014-12-22 20:53:10,122 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'mule'.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:106)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135)
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedApp(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:297)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployExplodedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:108)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployExplodedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:290)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:151)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:99)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
    at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
INFO  2014-12-22 20:53:10,137 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'examplejmsqueue' never started, nothing to dispose of
ERROR 2014-12-22 20:53:10,231 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer:
```

Comment: Posting your mule flow along will help!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to create a Mule application using the schema definition of mule 2.2 while your project probably is using a jar of a different version.

Change 2.2 for current or even better use the appropriate version number.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened because mule was unable to connect to Salesforce. 
Try following

- log in to salesforce using browser once. It may ask you to enter a validation code that it emailed you. This happens if you are using another machine.
- check proxy settings, if you are behind a proxy (most likely in your workplace). configure your SFDC global connector config with proxy settings if applicable. Your proxy settings will most likely be in Internet Explorer internet settings. Enter proxy user and password if applicable.
- simply give it time. In my case, I saw that eclipse was running a background task to get Salesforce objects. It took a minute or more.